# useEffect doesn't fire in the beginning when dependency is empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, react-hooks

I'm learning react by coding, here i have strange behaviour which is first time happening.
In my console i should be getting same values from state and from redux, but for some reason
first one gives me 'books from state undefined' and second one 'books from redux: {roman: [},fantasy:[]}'.
in my useEffect i have empty array, shouldnt it fire in the beginning when user comes to the page ?, why just one of them works and not other ?

```js
  const [choosebook, setChoosebook] = useState<any>("");


const books = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.library.books
  );
  
  
   useEffect(() => {
    setChoosebook(books.book);
  }, []);
  
   console.log(
    "books from state: ", choosebook,
    "books from redux: ", books.book
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code looks okay. The problem comes from that the state is set correctly in the `useEffect` hook, but `useEffect` and `useState` runs asynchronously, so there is no guarantee that it will finish by the time the `console.log` runs.

You can try to wrap around the `console.log` line with another `useEffect` hook, which has the `choosebook` as a depedency.

```
const [choosebook, setChoosebook] = useState<any>("");


const books = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.library.books
  );
  
  
   useEffect(() => {
    setChoosebook(books.book);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(
    "books from state: ", choosebook,
    "books from redux: ", books.book
  );
  }, [choosebook]);
```

Comment: how to make it work that in my console i could see values in both ?

Comment: Updated answer with example

Comment: you have used another useEffect here, but i want to use 'choosebook' somewhere in the beginning, but it shows undefined, and i dont want to use books.book, so how to have values in 'choosebook' in the beginning ?

Comment: Wait in a useEffect hook until it becomes anything else than undefined.

Comment: i want to use 'choosebook' right from the start but it says undefined, how to make those values available in 'choosebook' from start ? like it is available in 'books.book' ?

Comment: Than pass it as a parameter from the parent element. Like `<MyElement books={choosebook}/>`

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is being called after a render.

First you see your `console.log` with `choosebook` being empty during the first render.

Only after that `setChoosebook` is being invoked inside the `useEffect`.

EDIT:

You can initialize the value of `choosebook` with the value you get from Redux:

```js
const books = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.library.books
);
const [choosebook, setChoosebook] = useState<any>(books.book);
```

Comment: i want to use 'choosebook' right from the start but it says undefined, how to make those values available in 'choosebook' from start ? like it is available in 'books.book' ?

Comment: thats why im using useEffect to initialize it right in the beginning...

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: i'm still getting undefined